# Explanation on what image caching code does

Tags: swift, image

Can someone explain how this image caching code works? I understand a task is being done to download the contents of the imageURL, checks to if error are present and displays it on the main thread. But what is the use of forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString?

```
func downloadImage(from urlString: String ) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        storeCache(url: url)
    }
    
    func storeCache(url:URL){
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString) as? UIImage {
            self.image = cachedImage
        }else {
            let _: Void = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                if error != nil { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                        imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString)
                        self.image = downloadedImage
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cache is basically a fancy `[url: image]` dictionary. It allows the device to request once and then remember images until the app is closed.

Every time you need an image, your app will check the cache, just like a dictionary and ask if there's already a downloaded image from that url.

`if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: url.absoluteString... // empty`

Of course, when they first run the app, the cache will be empty. So it grabs the image from the internet and stores it in the cache, remembering which url it came from.

`imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: url.absoluteString... // cache the image`

From now on whenever it needs an image from that same url, it will check the cache and see you've already downloaded it. No more requests.

`if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: url.absoluteString... // something there!`